# Find offset relative to parent scrolling div instead of window

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, overflow, scrolltop

I have a scrolling element inside a window.

Say a division having a class "currentContainer" with overflow auto and that division contains huge amount of text so that it is definitely large enough to be scrolling.

Now I have to do some calculations based on how much the "currentContainer" has scrolled down + what is the offset of a specific element from its parent scrolling div (that is "currentCoantainer").

But while calculating offset I always get the offset of the inner child element with regard to window not with the "currentContainer".

[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/arpitajain/677phzuq/)

@Shikkediel I also tried using `position().top` instead of `offset().top` but is is also giving the same result. Have a look at it :

[JS FIDDLE 2](http://jsfiddle.net/arpitajain/97weogv9/)

Please do not suggest using :

```
$("<reference of scrolling element").scrollTop() 
+ 
$("<reference of child element whose offset I want to calculate>").offset().top
```

Because this is going to complicate my actual calculations which I am about to do beyond this.

Reason for why I do not want to use the above mentioned approach is that I am trying to modify an existing code which is already too messy but is working perfectly with regard to window I just have to update it so that it starts working relative to its parent scrolling div.

I tried using above mentioned approach but it opened a box of crabs for me. because functions are too much tightly coupled. So I think if I can get  simple and straight solution i.e. replacing `.offset().top`  with something else.

---

I tried debugging the code and still no luck I have added the actual code at http://jsfiddle.net/arpitajain/kwkm7com/

P.S. It is actual code but not complete I think The rest of the code was not needed for this error.

Comment: Not very clear what you are asking but look into `.position()`, this is offset relative to the parent.

Comment: Okay I will re frame my sentence.

Comment: Cheers. A good description ups the chances of finding a solution. :-)

Comment: Sorry for the bad English, but I have tried explaining things in detail, let me know If I am unable to explain something.

Comment: Your question is still not clear.. Can you explain using example 'px' units and some mspaint image cues ?

Comment: I've removed the answer because it didn't really offer a solution after all. And it seems a workaround was found in the form of a compromise.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could just subtract the offset of the parent element from the offset of the child element. Will that complicate the other things you need to do as well?

```
$(".getoffset").offset().top - $(".getoffset").offsetParent().offset().top
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kmLr07oh/2/

Comment: Great Answer, Thank you!

Comment: Some notes to add: \
1. Make sure your Parent_Div is **not dynamically changing**. \
-- so better use a `**fixed element reference** for the Parent_Div`, inside of using something like `Child_Element_ToGetOffsetRelToParentDiv.parent` \
1. If you are inside a **scrollable Parent_Div**, maybe you would like to add **`+ Parent_Div.scrollTop;`**. \
so eg: `const offset = Child_Element_ToGetOffsetRelToParentDiv.getBoundingClientRect().top - Parent_Div.getBoundingClientRect().top + Parent_Div.scrollTop;`

Answer (score 12):

This is probably what you are looking for

```
var scrollOffset = $('.container .element')[0].offsetTop - $('.container')[0].offsetTop;
```

and in Vanilla JS

```
var scrollOffset = document.querySelector('.container .element').offsetTop - document.querySelector('.container').offsetTop;
```

———————————

If you want background this should get you most of the way there:

```
// Position of first element relative to container top
var scrollTop = $(".container .element").offset().top - $(".container").offset().top;

// Position of selected element relative to container top
var targetTop = $(".container > *").offset().top - $(".container").offset().top;

// The offset of a scrollable container
var scrollOffset = scrollTop - targetTop;

// Scroll untill target element is at the top of its container
$(".container").scrollTop(scrollOffset);
```

Also see: [Calculate offset top of elements inside of a scrollable div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46725981/calculate-offset-top-of-elements-inside-of-a-scrollable-div/50616042#50616042)

Comment: The Edited part of your answer works exactly as I expected.

Answer (score 8):

A vanilla Javascript solution would be:

```
const el = document.querySelector('.getoffset');
const offset = el.getBoundingClientRect().top - el.offsetParent.getBoundingClientRect().top;
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/njb1xcz0/

Comment: Doesn't work, the resulting numbers are way too big. The entire space before the scrolling div is also added which is not correct.

Comment: in the fiddle that I've posted, the values calculated with the vanilla JS are identical to those calculated via jquery. please provide a fiddle so that I can reproduce your issue.

Comment: I think my scroll container might have missed the `position: relative` which another comment somewhere mentioned. None of the answers I found about that topic included that important point, otherwise `offsetTop` (the main part of any solution) just doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In my test

```
//has the same value
console.log(
    'compare:',
    $("#element").offset().left - $("#container").offset().left,
    $("#element").position().left
);
```

Witch mean it gets **absolute position** to parent. To get **relative position** to parent, I use:

```
let relative_position_x = Element.position().left + scroller.scrollLeft();
let relative_position_y = Element.position().top + scroller.scrollTop();
```